# Is there a way to customize the TestCafe Studio template for rendering JS?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a collection of utilities and modeled pages that our TestCafe tests rely on. I'm working on a POC to see if we could utilize that code from within the TestCafe Studio. I assume there is a template somewhere that is used to help generate the JS code that results from pressing the `Convert to JavaScript` button, but I may be wrong. If it exists, I'd like to know how I can add some imports to the top of it.

Alternatively, if there is a way to run a script before the tests run, then maybe I can import my utilities and pages and add them to the context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe Studio does not allow modifying a template to generate JS code using the `Convert to JavaScript` button.

However, you still can use your utilities and scripts inside the TestCafe Studio test code. Please refer to the following help topic for more details: [Custom Scripts](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts).

Comment: Is there a way to use the scripts outside of a test or fixture, preferably run a script before the first test runs?

Comment: Codeless tests only support beforeEach and afterEach hooks. However, if you convert your tests to JS, you can use fixture hooks that look more suitable in your case.
Please see the following articles:
[https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401074/test-concepts/hooks](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401074/test-concepts/hooks)
[https://testcafe.io/documentation/402785/reference/test-api/fixture/before](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402785/reference/test-api/fixture/before)